# Which Django Form Field can provide me a HTML output of <input type="range" />?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I've got a html form with this input:

```
    <input id="duration_slider" type="range" min="1" max="168" value="48" />
```

However I'd now like to convert this slider to a django form field, so I can use it in a Django form. The field name is `duration` so I'll change the `id` to `id=id_duration`.

What would my models.py and forms.py looks like for this field?

Currently it's just:

```
class AdvertisePost(Post):
    ...
    duration = models.IntegerField(default=48)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class AdvertisePostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    duration = ?

    class Meta:
        model = AdvertisePost
        fields = [
            ...
            #'duration'    
        ]
```

**EDIT**

**views**

```
if options_form.is_valid():
    instance = options_form.save(commit=False)
    print(instance.duration) #prints the default value every time
```

form field

```
duration = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'type':'range', 'step': '1', 'min': '1', 'max': '148'}), required=False)
```

Comment: Try like this : `forms.IntegerField(widget=NumberInput(attrs={'type':'range', 'step': '2'}))
`

Comment: Perfect, this seems to work. thanks.

Comment: but for the min and max I think you have to check before , for reference you can take look here https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/20674

Comment: Hmm it's outputting the exact same value every time (the default value) - could this be related? I added in `min` and `max` in the form widget but doesn't seem to do anything. Any idea? I've added my updated code in my edit.

Answer (score 6):

Oof two years! I'm very late

```
class AdvertisePostForm(forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta:
         model = AdvertisePost
         fields = ['duration', ...]
         widgets = {
         'duration': forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'range'})
         }
```

Hope this works
edit:
You will need some javascript if you want to display it tho and some of work in the backend side to turn it into Int